# Sorting data according to an array

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm trying to write an Excel macro to sort some data I have according to an array.

It's not giving me an error buts it's also sorting in alphabetical order which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm working on a Mac.

```vb
Sub AutoFormat()

    ' Define the order of the status values
    Dim statusOrder(1 To 15) As String
    statusOrder(1) = "Open/Gathering proposals"
    statusOrder(2) = "Proposal Received/Construction Review"
    statusOrder(3) = "Ready To send"
    statusOrder(4) = "Sent to owner / Waiting for approval"
    statusOrder(5) = "Approval received / Add to QB/ Send deposit invoice"
    statusOrder(6) = "Waiting for deposit"
    statusOrder(7) = "Deposit received"
    statusOrder(8) = "Vendor deposit paid"
    statusOrder(9) = "PM Schedule"
    statusOrder(10) = "Work To Start"
    statusOrder(11) = "Vendor work completed"
    statusOrder(12) = "Send Final Invoice"
    statusOrder(13) = "Waiting for Final Payment"
    statusOrder(14) = "Final Payment received / sent to vendor / Closed"
    statusOrder(15) = "Canceled / Owner denied / On Hold"

    'Format cells A:H to bold font, font size 14, center align, auto width with maximum width of 50, and wrap text
    Range("A:H").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 14
        .WrapText = True
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Columns("A:H").ColumnWidth = Application.Min(50, .Columns("A:H").ColumnWidth)
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .EntireRow.AutoFit
    End With
    
    'Sort the data based on the order of the status values
    Dim lastRow1 As Long
    lastRow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 'Assuming Status is in column C
    Dim statusPosition As Variant
    Dim statusPositions() As Variant
    ReDim statusPositions(1 To lastRow1)
    For i = 2 To lastRow1
        statusPosition = Application.Match(CStr(Range("C" & i).Value), statusOrder, 0)
        Debug.Print "i: " & i
        Debug.Print "Range('C" & i & ").Value: " & Range("C" & i).Value
        Debug.Print "statusPosition: " & statusPosition
        If IsError(statusPosition) Then
            statusPosition = 0
        End If
        statusPositions(i) = statusPosition
    Next i
    Debug.Print "lastRow: " & lastRow1
    Debug.Print "statusPositions: " & statusPosition
    Range("A1:H" & lastRow1).Sort key1:=Range("C1"), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=Application.Index(statusPositions, 0, 1), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you write the statusPosition into a spare column (maybe I), sort on that column and  then delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Just in case someone will find a use for it as I did.

```
            'Sort the data based on the order of the status values
    Dim lastRow1 As Long
    lastRow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 'Assuming Status is in column C
    Dim statusPosition As Variant
    Dim statusPositions() As Variant
    ReDim statusPositions(1 To lastRow1)
    For i = 2 To lastRow1
        statusPosition = Application.Match(CStr(Range("C" & i).Value), statusOrder, 0)
        If IsError(statusPosition) Then
            statusPosition = 0
        End If
        statusPositions(i) = statusPosition
        Range("I" & i).Value = statusPosition ' Write statusPosition to column "I"
    Next i
    
        Range("A1:I" & lastRow1).Sort key1:=Range("I2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    
    'Delete the temporary column "I"
    Columns("I:I").Delete
```